# jupyterlab button event not working

Tags: events, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

This code work in jupyter notebook, but doesn't work in jupyterlab:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    print("Button clicked.")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Env:

- MacOsX 10 10.12.2
- Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- Jupyter Notebook 5.4.0
- Jupyter Lab 0.31.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current, still know as issue ... but [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1286) I found a solution.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
button = widgets.Button(description='Display Chart')
out = widgets.Output()
def on_button_clicked(b):
    button.description = 'clicked'
    with out:
        print('Ay')

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
widgets.VBox([button, out])
```

Comment: Humm, at the moment with the latest version of Jupyter even this is not working on the normal notebooks